# How to search data from master table in oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am creating form in 10g

- 3 fields non-database with LOV
- Tabular form database block with LOV
- Search button

I have master table stored in database and created another table to store only primary key values from 3 master tables. I want to search data from master table

In search button code:

```
SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('BLOCK_NAME',
                    default_where,
                   'COLUMN_NAME=' ||''''|| NVL(:BLOCK_NAME.FIELD_NAME, 0) ||''''
                  );
EXECUTE_QUERY;
```

When button press then show error invalid number because another table i created store primary key values i want to search data from master table

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you described. What is that "another table" used for; OK, you store primary keys from 3 "master" tables, but - why?

Anyway: if `FIELD_NAME` is numeric, then it makes sense to apply `NVL` to it and "convert" `NULL` into `0` (zero), but - if it is not, then it might be a problem (*).

That's what all those single quotes you use suggest - that `FIELD_NAME` is a character field, so you're enclosing its value into single quotes. It is difficult to follow that many quotes, so - why don't you switch to something simpler, such as

```
'column_name=' || chr(39) || :block_name.field_name || chr(39)
```

where `chr(39)` represents a single quote.

To continue a possible problem (*) with `NVL`: if that's the case, consider using a different syntax and avoid `NVL`:

```
'column_name=' || chr(39) || :block_name.field_name || chr(39) ||
                   ' or ' || :block_name.field_name || ' is null'
```

Comment: i created another table and store primary key values from 3 different master table because as per company rule we don't show primary values to client only show other fields without primary key. User select values from tabular and saved data into database with primary key values. Now search data on the base master tables

Comment: That doesn't mean that you should do what you're doing now. Use the primary key item, but don't display it on the canvas. In List of Values, select the primary key column value, but don't display it (set its width to 0 (zero)). Really, no need to reinvent the wheel, just use built-in Forms capabilities.